# Incorrect results using parameter in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report for which I created two datasets for.  One for the actual report and one for the parameter.

Dataset 1 is the report
Dataset 2 simply pulls the parameter that I want to report on from the table where it is stored.

When I run the report and select the parameter, it shows me all the values, but when I select one, I still get every record rather than just the records based on the parameter.

Dataset 1

```
SELECT stk.ItemCode AS ItemCode, stk.warehouse AS warehouse, 
     stk.Description AS Description, stk.Assortment AS Assortment, 
    Items.Class_02, stk.ItemGroup AS ItemGroup, stk.ItemStatus AS ItemStatus, 
    stk.ItemUnit AS ItemUnit, ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 dbo.bacoSalesPrice(p.ID, 
    0) FROM staffl p WHERE ({d '2019-05-27'} BETWEEN validfrom AND 
    ISNULL(validto,{d '9999-12-31'})) 
    AND prijslijst  = 'SALESPRICE' AND Items.ItemCode = artcode ORDER BY 
   artcode, validfrom desc),0) AS SalesPackagePrice, 
   ROUND((stk.Stock/stk.SalesPkg),2) AS Stock, ROUND((stk.Stock + 
   stk.QtyToBeReceived - stk.QtyToBeDelivered)/stk.SalesPkg,2) AS 
   AvailableStock, stk.SearchCode AS SearchCode FROM Items INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 
   v.magcode AS warehouse, 
   MAX(i.itemcode) AS ItemCode, 
   MAX(i.description_0) AS Description,  
   i.SearchCode AS SearchCode, 
   MAX(ia.Assortment) AS Assortment, 
   MAX(ia.Description_0) AS ItemGroup, 
   MAX(CASE
   WHEN i.condition = 'A' THEN 'Active'
   WHEN i.condition = 'B' THEN 'Blocked'
   WHEN i.condition = 'D' THEN 'Discontinued'
   WHEN i.condition = 'E' THEN 'Inactive'
   WHEN i.condition = 'F' THEN 'Future'
   END) AS ItemStatus, 
   ISNULL(MAX(a.purchasepackage), '-') AS ItemUnit,
   MAX(i.SalesPackagePrice) AS SalesPackagePrice, 
   MAX(v.bestniv) AS Minimum, 
   MAX(v.maxvrd) AS Maximum, 
   MAX(i.lev_crdnr) AS Supplier, 
   MAX(a.DeliveryTimeInDays) AS DeliveryTime, 
   MAX(ISNULL(a.SlsPkgsPerPurPkg,1)) AS SalesPkg, 
   ISNULL(Actual.Quantity,0) AS Stock 
  ,ISNULL(SUM(QtyToReceived),0) AS QtyToBeReceived 
  ,ISNULL(SUM(QtyToBeDelivered),0) AS QtyToBeDelivered 
  FROM items i 
  JOIN voorrd v ON i.itemcode=v.artcode 
  LEFT JOIN itemaccounts a ON i.itemcode=a.itemcode and i.lev_crdnr=a.crdnr 
  AND i.itemcode IS NOT NULL AND a.itemcode IS NOT NULL  AND i.lev_crdnr IS N 
 NOT NULL AND a.crdnr IS NOT NULL 
JOIN ItemAssortment ia ON ia.Assortment = i.Assortment 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.TempToBeReceivedDelivered#3E5BBBE6#FB7B#4309#9CE1#560885B9BF94# budget
 ON v.magcode = budget.warehouse AND i.ItemCode = budget.artcode 
 AND v.magcode IS NOT NULL AND budget.warehouse IS NOT NULL  AND i.ItemCode IS NOT NULL AND budget.artcode IS NOT NULL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (SELECT GX.artcode, GX.warehouse, 
 GX.Quantity, 
 GX.AmtActualStock, GX.TotalCnt, 
 CASE WHEN GX.FreeQuantity > GX.CurrentQuantity THEN (CASE WHEN GX.CurrentQuantity < 0 THEN 0 ELSE GX.CurrentQuantity END) ELSE 
 (CASE WHEN GX.FreeQuantity < 0 THEN 0 ELSE GX.FreeQuantity END) END As FreeQuantity 
 FROM ( 
SELECT sb.ItemCode AS artcode, SUM(CASE WHEN sb.Date <= {d '2019-05-27'} THEN sb.Quantity END) as Quantity, 
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN sb.Date <= {d '2019-05-27'} THEN sb.StockAmount END),2) as AmtActualStock, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN sb.Date <= {d '2019-05-27'} THEN sb.Quantity END) as CurrentQuantity, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN sb.Date <= {d '2019-05-27'} THEN sb.FreeStock END) AS FreeQuantity, sb.Warehouse, 
 SUM(sb.GbkmutCount) AS TotalCnt 
 FROM StockBalances sb WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN Items ON sb.ItemCode = Items.ItemCode JOIN ItemAssortment ON Items.Assortment = ItemAssortment.Assortment 
 --WHERE  Items.Class_02 in @Customer 
 GROUP BY sb.ItemCode, sb.WareHouse, Items.Class_02  
 HAVING SUM(sb.GbkmutCount) > 0) GX) AS Actual  
 ON Actual.artcode = i.ItemCode AND Actual.warehouse = v.magcode  AND Actual.artcode IS NOT NULL AND i.ItemCode IS NOT NULL  AND Actual.warehouse IS NOT NULL AND v.magcode IS NOT NULL 
 WHERE i.type IN ('S', 'B')
 AND i.ItemCode BETWEEN '0030122186' AND 'XS45000'
 AND i.Condition IN ('A')
 AND ((i.IsSalesItem <> 0)) AND i.Type IN ('S', 'B')
 AND 1=1 
 GROUP BY v.magcode , i.itemcode, i.SearchCode, Actual.Quantity 
) stk ON items.ItemCode = stk.ItemCode
INNER JOIN grtbk ON Items.GLAccountDistribution = grtbk.reknr
 ORDER BY stk.ItemCode
```

Dataset 2

```
SELECT Class_02, ItemCode FROM Items
```

Parameter in SSRS is set to Get values from Query, Value field: Class_02
Label field: Class_02

Comment: The only parameter in DataSet 1 is commented out.  Does that explain it?  Note the line:  
--WHERE  Items.Class_02 in @Customer

Comment: The parameter that @Rono pointed out is also a LEFT JOIN so it wouldn't filter out the desired records even if it was being used, just the data from the `Actual` subquery would be NULL.

Comment: I had it commented out so I could run it in SSMS.   But when it's there, it doesn't work.   @HannoverFist what would you recommend?

Comment: Have you tried moving the `WHERE` clause to the end right before the `ORDER BY` clause? What happens then?

Comment: As @StevenWhite said, the WHERE should be at the end so it applies to the overall query. You'll need to rework the query so that the `Items.Class_02` field can be used in the main query.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked!